# How do I change a color of a Html element in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, canvas

I have made a post on this before however, it was not in a canvas, but when you try to apply this to a canvas It gives an error along the lines of Cant change the color of undefined so I thought it was an error of the way I defined it so I would add it to a class then run it as changing the color of all elements in the class, but when I try it the canvas just disappears..  but getting to the point is there an easy way to change the color of a HTML element in a canvas or am I just crazy

**Code**

```js
var myGamePiece = el.classList.add("class1");
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
  myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
      return;
    }
  }
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
    x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    minHeight = 20;
    maxHeight = 200;
    height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1) + minHeight);
    minGap = 50;
    maxGap = 200;
    gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -1;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  myScore.text = "SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myScore.update();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
  myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}

function Test() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("class1").style.background = "yellow";
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.class1 {}
```

```html
<body onload="startGame()">
  <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
  <p> Credit To W3Schools.com </p>
  <button onclick="test">Click To Change Player's Color</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't find any code that you use to change the color of a html element.

Comment: hold on let me update it put in the wrong code

Comment: fixed the code found the right one

Comment: el is not defined.You code has many error.

Comment: If you want to change the color of the small square, you can create a new `myGamePiece`.

Comment: Your code is running on the body load... So you would need to change the color before you start the game.

Comment: so I would have to have a start screen to pause it before it starts?

Comment: how would I do this I'm clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code starts with: `var myGamePiece = el.classList.add("class1");`el is not defined but anyway myGamePiece needs to be a component as created in startGame, it is not an ordinary HTML element.

It is the creation of that component that the color is set. Currently the color is hardcoded as 'red'. To change the color you need to set a variable, let's call it playerColor, and use that in the component creation call rather than 'red'.

You are using function test to set up a color so let's change the test function to do that, but you need to get that color set up before startGame otherwise the canvas will have the incorrect color for the piece (or no set color).

```
var playersColor = "red"; //the default value if the player doesn't change it
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, playersColor, 10, 120);//use playersColor
  myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
  myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
      return;
    }
  }
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
    x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    minHeight = 20;
    maxHeight = 200;
    height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1) + minHeight);
    minGap = 50;
    maxGap = 200;
    gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -1;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  myScore.text = "SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myScore.update();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
  myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}

function test() {
  playersColor = "yellow";
}

<body>
  <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
  <p> Credit To W3Schools.com </p>
  <button onclick="test()">Click To Change Player's Color</button>
  <button onclick="startGame();">Click to start the game</button>
</body>
```

...............................................................................

Although the following errors are not fundamentally what is causing non-changing of the player's color, they contain some coding errors which it might be helpful to point out for the future.

```
<button onclick="test">Click To Change Player's Color</button>
<script>
    function Test() {
         document.getElementsByClassName("class1").style.background = "yellow";
</script>
```

The onclick="test" does nothing - you may be confusing the structure element.onclick = test - which sets which function is run on the element being clicked - with the syntax for the onclick="test();" needed in the button element attributes.

A further error is that the function is called Test, not test. Javascript is case sensitive. Also you need to select the one element with class1, not retrieve a collection of such elements, so you can set its style (if that is useful, is it?).

Comment: Im not at my computer right now so this should change the elements color or would I have to change the color of the element before I load the canvas

Comment: You'd have to change the fill color before you draw the element onto the canvas as a canvas has no knowledge of elements, it doesn't understand structure at all.

Comment: oh so I can just not start the game onload and run the document.getElementbyID("Mygamepeice").style.background = "Blue"; then make the player hit a start button you saying?

Comment: Yes, getting the player to hit  a button to start the game once they have been given a chance to select a color is the right way round. I have updated my answer to describe how to set the color at the start. You could embellish this and let them change color during the game by adding a color property (like you already have gravity for example) but unless I've misunderstood I don't think this is what you were asking?

Comment: Yeah that’s what I wanted to do thanks you

Comment: Hey when i try the code it does not change the color it stays at red what do i do (no errors)

Comment: Apologies, the brackets were missing from the onclick call to test. I’ve put them in. Your browsers dev tools console should have shown an error.